# Double SSH tunnelling for SMB shared folder

Tags: ssh, samba, ssh-tunneling, file-sharing

I am actually working from `PC1` (using Mac OSX) on a distant computer(Linux) PC2 using `SSH`.

This distant computer `PC2` does not have any connection to Internet but is in a network with a `PC3` (Windows XP) which has no internet connection.

I shared a folder on my `PC3` desktop and I would like to be able to use it directly on `PC1`, using OSX.

I think it's a double SSH tunnelling problem here.

How can I double SSH my packets in a way that I will be able to use my shared folder's `PC3` from `PC1`?

Everything should be done from Terminal if possible, and in a one-line command.

My Mac OSX computer has an Internet access, but it's the only one.

Comment: They're *not* all connected, right? Thus you need to go from PC1 via PC2 to PC3?  (I don't quite see the need for SSH here, are we talking about a home setup or a hostile environment (i.e.g work place)?)

Comment: You haven't been clear enough here; "This distant computer PC2 does not have any connection to Internet but is in a network with a PC3" So how can PC2 and PC1 be connected? If they are on the same network then please state this

Comment: PC2 and PC3 are in a virtual network using VMware. It's in a laboratory context, so I don't know what is the real architecture behind the laboratory.

Answer (score 1):

```
MACOSX-PC1$ ssh -L 445:<WINDOWS-PC3-ADDREES>:445 yourlogin@<LINUX-PC2-ADDRESS>
```

... now you are binding the 445 port (the SMB TCP port) of PC3 on your PC1 loopback interface... Now you need to recognise the local condivision at MacOSX, I don't know how!!

Alternatively I suggest to mount SMB condivision on PC2, then accesses to this folder from PC3 by sftp!

Alternatively you can install a Openvpn server on your linux server and then you can full accessing to your remote network!

Comment: This is exactly what I've done yesterday, I this will not work

Comment: After creating the ssh tunnel, check if the socket server is accessible: `telnet localhost 445`